# Classical harmonic oscillator Green's functions

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, greens-functions

A recent paper [(Modeling heat transport in crystals and glasses
from a unified lattice-dynamical approach)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-11572-4) derived expressions for thermal conductivity in a system of harmonic oscillators that decay with individual time constants determined by their anharmonic interactions.

In this paper, they wrote the Hamiltonian of a classical harmonic operator in complex amplitude coordinates:

$$ H=\sum_n\omega_n|\alpha_n|^2,$$

where $\omega_n$ is the frequency of oscillator $n$ and

$$ \alpha_n =\sqrt{\frac{\omega_n}{2}}\xi_n + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2\omega_n}}\pi_n$$

is a "complex amplitude," where $\xi_n$ and $\pi_n$ are the mode amplitudes and momenta, respectively.

Now, the authors take an ensemble average, $\langle\alpha^*_n(t)\alpha_m(0)\rangle$, and   claim that

$$ \langle\alpha^*_n(t)\alpha_m(0)\rangle=\delta_{nm}\frac{k_BT}{\omega_n}e^{i\omega_nt},$$

where the term on the right-hand side is a "single-mode Green's function".

I'm confused about this ensemble average average, why it equals the right-hand side, and why it's called a "single-mode Green's function". Has anyone seen anything like this before?

- Why does $ \langle\alpha^*_n(t)\alpha_m(0)\rangle=\delta_{nm}\frac{k_BT}{\omega_n}e^{i\omega_nt}$?
- Why is $\frac{k_BT}{\omega_n}e^{i\omega_nt}$ called a Green's function?
- Where should I read to learn more about this stuff?